# How can I see the SMS status in twilio dashboard?

Tags: asp.net, twilio

I try to send SMS with Twilio account.
The program run as well, returning the status "queue" - but in the Twilio dashboard I see nothing. (any list of SMS messages.)
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the SMS was not sent. After sending, the dashboard is updated immediately and you can see all the messages sent.
The problem may have been that I was not an administrator in the account. I opened a new account and the sending was immediately successful.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).